# calling stored procedure from asp.net page returns Parameter <Column_Name> not found in the collection.

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am Trying to call a stored procedures that returns a single value from a table where the table name is parameterised. on calling the SP it returns the following error

**

```
> system.argumentexception: Parameter 'tableName' not found in the collection.
```

**

my stored procedure is :

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectDynamicTable`(IN tableName VARCHAR(6))
BEGIN

SET @table1 := tableName;
SET @sql_text := concat('SELECT MAX(Sl_No) FROM ',@table1,';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

and my c# code that calls it is :

```
  MySqlCommand cmdSelect = new MySqlCommand("selectDynamicTable", con);
                cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table1", comp_code.ToString().ToLower());
                //cmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MySqlDataReader dr1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr1.Read())
                {
                    int query1 = dr1.GetInt32(0);
                    query1 += 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in Mysql but I think it should look something like this. Others may correct if I made an error somewhere.

Additionaly please read this tutorial about variables: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/variables-in-stored-procedures.aspx .

Lastly if you are using dr1 as a variable name for anything more than testing, I would recommend changing the name to something reconizable.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectDynamicTable`(IN tableName VARCHAR(6))
(
IN tableName VARCHAR(6)
)
BEGIN

SET @sql_text := concat('SELECT MAX(Sl_No) FROM ', tableName, ';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;

END |

delimiter ;





MySqlCommand cmdSelect = new MySqlCommand("selectDynamicTable", con);
cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", comp_code.ToString().ToLower());
cmd.Parameters["tableName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

//cmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
MySqlDataReader dr1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
while (dr1.Read())
{
    int query1 = dr1.GetInt32(0);
    query1 += 1;
}
```

Comment: This is just the test code here. I am not allowed to expose the production code in a public forum. Thank you for your prompt reply.